# How can a company create a tag?

Tags: feature-request, support

There is a lot of information about the topic related for creating a tag and I understand it. But my situation is as follows:

Game Technologies is the company working on DICE+, a wireless dice that sends the result over bluetooth to any tablet (digital) device.

During GDC 13 we released the Developer Kit and our developer website. Internally, we decided that it would be best to have a community on Stack Overflow. Developers are used to this site and there is no point in creating yet, another place for talking about development.

Sadly, in the company we don't have anyone with a high rank, nor anybody knows anyone else. This makes it impossible to create a tag.

I talked to the support team, and their advice was to ask someone on the site to create a tag for us. I did, and the response wasn't good.

This is our situation and problem. How can we solve this?

Comment: I'd say companies don't need a tag. Technologies might do. Are there already questions related to the particular technology? Tags are not created in a void. They are created because there are questions which would benefit from it. P.s. I'm guessing you mean "Developer Kit"? Releasing Developer Kids might have all kinds of problematic consequences.

Comment: The question is not what tag to create. The question is: what a company should to if its want to create a tag, but dose not have enough points to do so.

Especially when the solution provided by Stackoverflow dose not work.

Comment: Nothing. If there are questions related to a particular technology, the tags will be created by the community. If you have a list of questions requiring a particular tag, but you can't create it, tell us and we'll have a look.

Comment: I can remember an exact duplicate of this question, but can't find it right now...

Comment: @DawidGatti Until there are questions about it, the tag doesn't need to exist. When questions actually start being asked then the tag will either be created by the person asking the question (if they have sufficient rep) or by other users when they see it's necessary.

Comment: But without a proper tag, we can't monitor it and help the developer.

Comment: @DawidGatti That is not our concern. And you're saying there are currently no relevant questions asked? If there are, show us.

Comment: @DawidGatti You're looking at it from the wrong side. SO doesn't create the tag and then get the questions, we get the question(s) then create the tag. If you can find even a single question that would benefit from the tag right now, add a link to it in your question and I'm sure somebody will create the tag for you.

Comment: @Bart, i don't know if there are any. If we had a official tag, we could monitor the situation. And make sure to help anyone asking question related to DICE+. I'm perplex by our stand on this mater. I would like to make the whole experience of asking any question related to D+ as smooth as possible, and this seams to be a bed thing.

I thinks that a company should be able to contact a employ at Stackoverflow and ask for a tag, while explaining the situation what it is for. This could even be a new source of revenue.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist ok, if this is how want to have it, ok. I think there is room for improvement when it comes to creating tag for companies.

Comment: @DawidGatti Long story short, we'd love to create a tag for you, if there is content on the site which needs it. Until then you will have to monitor the site through searches and not via a tag. If you can find a question (or ideally several questions) which needs the tag, we'll help you out to create it. As for revenue, SO already has sponsored tags, but even those are not created in the void. It's not how the system works. Get your community to ask questions here and you'll have your tag in no time.

Comment: Users only need [1500 rep](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) to create a tag, if they have any questions on it, they can be tagged. Perhaps you could set up a google alert for "StackOverflow DICE+".

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at this from the wrong point of view. While I appreciate that from your perspective it would be useful to have the tag so that you can monitor it, and see when questions start being asked, that's not how things work on StackOverflow. The questions come first and then the tag is created, either by the person asking the question (if they have sufficient reputation to do so) or by another user with the privilege.

As it stands currently, from what I can see there are [zero questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22DICE%2B%22) containing the phrase "DICE+" so there's no need (from our perspective) for the tag to exist yet.

Comment: One way they could get the tag to exist would be to ask (and answer) some **good** questions related to their technology, then ask someone to add the tag to them.